# Android: createChooser not working for map it always open google map

Tags: java, android, android-intent, maps

it works in all devices below 6.0 open with shows available maps app like waze , google map , sygic .. but this chooser not showing in android nougat although there is not set any by default app . any help highly appreciated.

```
 String uri = "http://maps.google.com/maps?q=loc:"+24.871560+","+67.129752;
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse(uri));
    Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open with");
    startActivity(chooser);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can confirm that this is troublesome on Android 7.
On Android 8 things behave normal again.

For Android 7 i had luck changing

```
intent.setData(Uri.parse(uri));
```

to

```
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(uri), "text/html");
```

But only after installing a second browser like FireFox.

Now i can choose between Chrome and FireFox but choosing Chrome will bring up the Maps app.

What a terrible behaviour!